# Javascript slider isn't loading fast enough

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on [this website](http://decoster.stag-insusiteplatform.be/) and I noticed that when you go to a page that has a slider at the top, the different slides are shown all at the same time instead of only the first showing. This is only for a split second but gets very annoying.

Basically the js file handling the slider isn't loading fast enough. I moved the js file loading to the header but I still get this annoying effect.

I was wondering if there was a way to speed the loading up even more or if anyone has had this kind of problem and has an idea to resolve this.

Comment: reduce.http.requests

Comment: I used a no elegant but effective way to hide the loading process, by adding a div that hide the content until all the request return "done"... or at least the first ones does, then it slides out and leave the real slider. The div contains text that load faster logically and cover the "mess"... as I said, is not elegant, but it clean up the looks of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your css:

```
.insusite_banners{
   height:19.7vw
}
```

If you have access to `/sites/decoster/files/color/sita-c005118e/style.css` you can put it in the already declared rule

You could also delete that rule via javascript after it's done loading if you want perfection.